# Regional Zone Missing from Project Dropdown in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

While linking google accounts to specific BQ projects, I went to add the specific region (europe-west2) however I can no longer see it. I waited 24 hours and still not there.

Any ideas why? Tried the same on different projects but still no joy!